# SEARCH function in excel does not work correctly

Tags: excel, function

I am having a problem with the excel SEARCH function and the problem is that it takes some bad values ​​and others good. I put pictures to explain it better.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

To get an idea, in the Code field I need to show the letter of the note by looking for it at the bottom of the table. The function I have right now is the following `= SEARCH (G2; B9: F11; B11: F11)`, but as you can see in cells H3 and H4 it doesn't do it correctly for me. Anyone know what might be happening?

Comment: You want HLOOKUP not SEARCH.

Comment: `=HLOOKUP(G2;9:11;3;False)`

Comment: The exercise tells me that I have to use the SEARCH function

Comment: @ScottCraner That shows me #¿NAME?

Comment: you will need to translate to your language

Comment: And Search will not do what you want, my guess is that you are translating incorrectly.

Comment: `=BUSCARH(G2;9:11;3;FALSO)`